# C++ get matches from regex_iterator

Tags: c++, regex, class, object, iterator

I am trying to get some matches from a file by reading it line by line. My code is this:

```
std::regex e("id=\"(.+?)\"|title=\"(.+?)\"|summary=\"(.+?)\"|first=\"(.+?)\"|last=\"(.+?)\"");
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rit ( line.begin(), line.end(), e );
std::regex_iterator<std::string::iterator> rend;

while (rit!=rend) {
    std::cout << rit->str() << std::endl;
    ++rit;
}
```

I have tried using regex_search and smatch object, but it stops in the first match of the line. I found that regex_iterator does the job, but it gives me the whole match (e.g. id="123456", instead of 123456) which makes sense, but I need the number only.

According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_iterator/operator*/ dereferencing the iterator will give me a match_results object, but I don't know how to declare one (it always gives me bad arguments list. How can I get the iterator to give me an smatch object?

Comment: Last I heard, g++ regex is not working yet.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `str()` on a `match_results` object returns the entire current match. To see individual submatches, pass an index in the call:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rit->size(); ++i)
    std::cout << rit->str(i) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to loop over the matches, calling `regex_match` each time to get an updated  `match_results` object each time.